# Does Haskell provide min/max constants for the range of Int?

Tags: haskell, integer

Does Haskell provide any constants for knowing the limits of `Int`? I understand `Int` is platform-dependent, but nevertheless I would like to utilize it and to initialize some values at the extremes in my particular case. The equivalent constants (for instance) in C would be `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @shang's answer is good. But note that you might be better off using something like `Maybe Int` rather than a an `Int` with some default value.

Comment: "**Initialize** some values at the extremes"?? Are you sure you've quite understood what the functional style of programming is about?

Comment: There are some legitimate uses of maximum and minimum bounds for `Int`, but very few.  As @shachaf said, you probably want `Maybe Int`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The maximum and minimum bounds for different types are accessed via the [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) type-class using the values `minBound` and `maxBound`.

The values are polymorphic based on the context they are in, so in some cases you might have to explicitly indicate the type if the compiler is unable to infer it. E.g.

```
x = minBound :: Int
```